# How Can I insert some data while using JTA Entity Manager

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JBoss 7.1 AS in my application , JPA, Hibernate and MySql DB, I configured everything well and my program is fetching data from db normal. The problem is when I try to insert some data . I found out is the normal that JTA EntityManager cannot use get Transaction , so my question is how Can i insert some data to my db ?  Have no idea how Spring works so don't point me to that please, unless it's simple.

my persistance looks like that now:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence                    
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="EngineProject" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>



        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.itdevelopment.DAO.User</class>


    <properties>

      <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

and my what im trying to do is simple insert some data in the ManagedBean, User class , a a method:

```
      em.getTransaction().begin();

        User employee = new User();
        employee.setId(23);
        employee.setCompany("Coca cola");;
        employee.setLogin("James");

        em.persist(employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

as I said it returns:
      A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    So how Can I insert something ?

Thank you.
M

Comment: You're running inside a full-stack Java EE container using JTA. Declarative transactions are natively supported. Just make your components stateless session beans, and you'll have transactions without needing to explicitely start commit and rollback transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Spring framework than you need to configure Spring container properly. Pleae provide spring configuration and you DAO Class content here.

Here is a link how to do this properly

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate

In common case you just need

1.Configure spring and hibernate properly
2.Mark DAO methods as @Transactional with required modifier

Also take a look to Spring Data project that has out of the box solution for Hibernate

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/

Comment: The OP is running inside a Java EE container. He's not using Spring, and doesn't need to.